# Forging scapy packet from byte string

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

I have a packet (SCTP) that I received from a remote peer. This packet is a byte string. Now I'm looking for create a scapy packet from this "byte string".

Is there any way to do so with scapy?

Thks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, not by using [`Packet`](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/e89d8965748439adc253714316de7a9a35b8bd73/scapy/packet.py#L51) class but a subclass of `Packet`.

You basically have to find the right class within [the `scapy/contrib/` directory](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/tree/master/scapy/contrib) of Scapy sources.